# How to put citations (using BibTex) at the last chapter only (instead of at the end of every chapters)?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, bibtex, citations

I have a bookdown document citing articles using a bibtex bibliography file. I have a "References" section at the end of the book in which I put all my list of citations using `r if (knitr::is_html_output()) '# References {-}'`

However, I want to get rid of the references that appear automatically in every chapters, and I wish when I click on a citation link, to be directly send to the citation on the reference section at the end of my book.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you areusing the default `bookdown::gitbook` for HTML output. In that case you can adjust the `split_bib` variable via YAML headers, typically in `_output.yml`:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  split_bib: no
```

See `?bookdown::gitbook` for more options.

Comment: It's working !
I tried that configuration before but I guess I put it in the wrong way.
Thank you very much.